# Можно ли передать из XMLHttpRequest в XMLHttpRequest HttpOnly cookie?

Tags: javascript, cookie, xmlhttprequest, axios

У меня есть Spa приложение.
И в нём запрос авторизации `/Api/Login` на axios, который должен вернуть JWT токен в куках.
Куки защищённые HttpOnly.

Есть ли такая возможность что бы следующий axios запрос был с этим куками, которые были возвращены в запросе авторизации?

Answer (score 0):

Решение оказалось очень простым.
Если в любом ответе запроса `XMLHttpRequest` возвращаются `cookie` то они устанавливаются на всю страницу, и далее автоматически передаются в любой последующий `XMLHttpRequest`.
Ничего специального для этого делать не надо.